# Having issues using ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I have some issues reading a file in to a vector using fstream. I hav two similar functions, one for reading, one for writing a file.

```
    void Prime::writePrimes(void){
    int i = primes.size();
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("primes.txt", ios::out);
    if (fout.is_open()){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            fout << primes[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
void Prime::readPrimes(void){
ifstream fin;
fin.open("prime.txt", ios::in);
if (fin.is_open()){
    while (fin){
        int b;
        cin >> b;
        addPrimes(b);
    }
    fin.close();
}
}
```

While writePrime works just fine, readPrime doesn't go into the if condition.
Has someone an idea to solve the issue?

Comment: shouldn't you have `fin >> b;` instead of `cin >> b;` ? are you sure that this is not your problem ?

Comment: You named your files differently. I mean does `prime.txt` exist since you wrote `primes.txt`

Comment: @PiotrS. That should be an answer. And it's also yet another reason why `using namespace std;` is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @Angew I guess the different names of files (singular vs plural primes) are the real problem

Comment: @PiotrS. Right. It's a two-typo question!

Comment: Yet another fstream question that **doesn't bother to handle errors properly!** `if (fin.is_open()){ ... } else std::cerr << "Uh-oh, something went very wrong\n";` would have revealed the problem instantly. Grumble grumble does noone get taught how to check for errors these days.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `ios::out` for an `ofstream` and don't need to use `ios::in` for an `ifstream`, those are the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> b` should be `fin >> b`.  also a better way to control your reading loop would be

```
int b;
while (fin >>b)
    addPrimes(b);
```

Comment: This answer would be even better without the useless check for `is_open` (if you're not going to take some action when it _isn't_ open then checking for it is useless, as the `fin>>b` operation would fail when it's not open anyway)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I never even though about that.  I'll edit it.